# Executing Powershell Script from Scheduled Tasks does not create tables in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, powershell

I am working on a small project and I would like to execute a powershell script which executes another script. When i execute the main script on its own, it works properly, drops the tables and creates new, while when i execute the "scheduled task" script, it updates the first table(Playlist) and does not drop it, just doubles its content. While the second table(Song) it does not even drop nor put any content into it.

Here is my scheduled task script:

```
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 04:18pm -Daily
$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument 
"C:\Users\Matej\Desktop\getAllData.ps1"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "StartupScript_PS" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User - 
Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force
```

This is my main script:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -inputfile 
C:\Users\Matej\Desktop\SQLQuery.sql
function insertToDb($line, $PlaylistId){

$position = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(0)
$songName = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(1)
$artistName = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(2)
$link = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(4)

$PlaylistId = $PlaylistId.Replace('"',"")
$songName = $songName.Replace('"',"")
$artistName = $artistName.Replace('"',"")
$songName = $songName.Replace("'","")
$artistName = $artistName.Replace("'","")

$convertedId = [int]($PlaylistId)

$insertSongQuery = "
    INSERT INTO SONG
        (position,name,artist,link,playlist_id)
    VALUES
        ('$position',N'$songName',N'$artistName','$link','$convertedId')
    GO
"
Write-Output $songName
if($line.ToString().Split(',').Length -eq 5)
{
 Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -query $insertSongQuery -U vikiUser - 
 Password 1234 -Database ProjectDb
}

}

function getPlaylist{
$shortName = $PSItem.ToString().Split(',').Get(0);
$name = $PSItem.ToString().Split(',').Get(1);
$insertquery = "
 INSERT INTO PLAYLIST
       (name, type) 
 VALUES 
       ('$name','country') 
 GO 
"
$getPlaylistIdQuery = "
    SELECT ID
    FROM PLAYLIST 
    WHERE PLAYLIST.name = '$name'
    GO
 "
 Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -query $insertquery -U vikiUser -Password 
 1234 -Database ProjectDb 
 $convertedid =(Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -query $getPlaylistIdQuery - 
 U 
 vikiUser -Password 1234 -Database ProjectDb )| ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -Skip 2


 (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 
 https://spotifycharts.com/regional/$shortName/daily/latest/download).Content > 
 out.csv

 cat out.csv | Select-Object -Skip 2 | select -First 15 | ForEach-Object {insertToDb 
  $_ 
 $convertedid}


 }


 cat C:\Users\Matej\Desktop\countries.txt | ForEach-Object {getPlaylist($_)}
```

And this is my SQL script:

```
IF DB_ID('ProjectDb') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
use ProjectDb;
DROP TABLE SONG;
DROP TABLE PLAYLIST;
END

ELSE
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE ProjectDb;
END

 GO

    CREATE TABLE PLAYLIST(
    ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name nvarchar(255),
    type nvarchar(255),
     );
    
     CREATE TABLE SONG(
    ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    position nvarchar(255),
    name nvarchar(255),
    artist nvarchar(255),
    link nvarchar(255),
    playlist_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PLAYLIST(ID)
    );
```

Comment: Does the user SYSTEM has the same access rights to the database as the user you're using when testing the script on its own?

Comment: @PMental well ofcourse, the SYSTEM has all the rights

Comment: As long as you know for sure. The system user does not have automatic access if it's not excplicitly set up in the database. In most of our production databases it has zero rights.

Comment: @PMental thank you i will look up more into that